# In Magento how can I use the layouts in a custom theme folder instead of the base folder?

Tags: magento

I'm very new to Magento and going in at the deep end by building a custom theme from scratch.

I've added a folder to `app/design/frontend` and to `skin/frontend` to add in my custom theme and added in all the resources into the skins file.

I have then copied the layout folder from `app/design/frontend/base`  and changed the `page.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/default.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/reset.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/webfonts.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jqzoom.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/core.css</stylesheet></action>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/top_nav" name="top.nav" as="topNav"/>
                <block type="page/top_cart" name="top.cart" as="topCart"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_nav" name="nav" as="nav" template="page/html/nav.phtml"/>

            <block type="page/html_aside" name="aside" as="aside" template="page/html/aside.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content"/>

            <block type="page/html_newsletter" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="page/html/newsletter.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/html_features" name="features" as="features" template="page/html/features.phtml"/>

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"/>

        </block>

    </default>

</layout>
```

to fit with the layout i want, however when i go into the admin panel, I can't find any reference to my layout anywhere?

Any ideas how i can get my layout in my custom theme folder onto the custom pages?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Goto Design configuration tab (System -> Configuration -> Design tab).

Step 2:
From the Design tab, in Current package name, enter the name of the interface in which your new theme resides. Magento will automatically load the interface called ‘default’ if this box is left blank.

Step 3:
In Default (under Themes heading), enter the name of the new theme you’d like to load to your website/store. If you leave this box blank, Magento will automatically load only the theme called ‘default’ (Remember, no matter how you configure the design tab, Magento will automatically load the theme called ‘default’. If you assign a theme in the admin, that theme will simply load higher up in hierarchy, but will load along with the theme ‘default’. This will change in the upcoming stable release however, to give you full control over what themes are loaded into the store). Should you choose to load the theme separately depending on file type (layout, templates, skin or translation files), enter the name of the theme from which to grab the according file types.

Step 4:
When you’re done, click the button “Save config” and reload your store – Voila! You now see your new theme reflected in the frontend.

Click here for more infohttp://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Answer (score 0):

**Adding new page layout for Magento CMS pages**

Magento offers advanced e-commerce functionality, but we should not disregard classic CMS pages which fulfill your website with additional content. Commonly those pages are very rarely with content that has identical structure, so we need to create new template for them.

To make a new template, first we need to create phtml file with your template and save it in
app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/page
Then open local.xml (app/etc/local.xml). Somewhere on 55th line of code, right below

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

Insert following code:
    
    
    
    Title that will be shown in drop down menu in Admin panel
    page/template-title.phtml

- Code must be inside      tag

Example: local.xml

[image]

Result: CMS page in Admin panel with new layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all create proper folder structure for you custom theme.

```
i.e. app/design/frontend/yourtheme/

(yourtheme =  give a name to your theme or it can be "default")
```

then create a layout folder in your them and then copy respective file to define the layout changes.

Now you should have file with below path

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/layout/page.xml
```

Then Goto **System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes** in admin panel

Now set the theme name(i.e. yourtheme) against "default" input box.

Hope this helps..